# Groupbox text property inside a groupbox - smaller text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, groupbox

I'm having a situation where I have a groupbox encompasing all controls on my form.  Inside that groupbox I have another groupbox however the text for this groupbox is substantially smaller than the previous groupbox.  Is there a property to prevent this from happening?  I'm assuming it's smaller text because it's inside another groupbox but was just wondering if there's a way around it.

Comment: I created a quick program where I had a groupbox with a label and buttons. Within that groupbox I added a second groupbox. I added a label into the 2nd groupbox. The text size on these labels were the same. Please post some  code to help Stackoverflow users to get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: It's not labels insdie the groupbox, it's the text property of the groupbox itself that srhinks slightly. :)

Answer (score 1):

I nested a number of groupboxes and the more I added it did appear as though the text was smaller the lower I went. I measured the length of the text with a ruler and they are actually the same size. I am not sure if this is what is happening to you, but perhaps the effect is what is called a [Ponzo illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponzo_illusion). I am very interested if you measure yours and what the result is.